# MaterialUI (MUI). How to pass handlers via props to DataGrid component (for using them in column type=actions)

Tags: material-ui

The docs say: https://mui.com/components/data-grid/columns/

> If the column type is 'actions', you need to provide a getActions
> function that returns an array of actions available for each row
> (React elements). You can add the showInMenu prop on the returned
> React elements to signal the data grid to group these actions inside a
> row menu.
>
> ```
> {
>   field: 'actions',
>   type: 'actions',
>   getActions: (params: GridRowParams) => [
>     <GridActionsCellItem icon={...} onClick={...} label="Delete" />,
>     <GridActionsCellItem icon={...} onClick={...} label="Print" showInMenu />,
>   ]
> }
> ```

How to pass via props onClick handlers?

```
<DataGrid deleteHandler={...} printHandler={...} />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry for stupid question. Of course we can pass handlers in columns prop :))) But I have found even better solution. I don't use calback handlers in `action` column, but I use  component.

```
getActions: (params: any) => [
                <GridActionsCellItem
                    icon={<OpenIcon />}
                    label='Open'
                    component={Link}
                    to={`/counterparties/${params.id}`}
                />
```

Comment: hey how to add handler to column?

Comment: look at `getActions` in docs examples

Answer (score 2):

The docs actually explain how to add handler:

Visit [Special properties](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#special-properties) then scroll down a bit then click **Show the full source** icon

Basically we need to declare columns inside our functional component where the handler resides, but wrap the columns array using `useMemo()` to prevent unnecessary rerender.

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        field: 'actions',
        type: 'actions',
        width: 80,
        getActions: (params) => [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<DeleteIcon />}
            label="Delete"
            onClick={deleteUser(params.id)}
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<SecurityIcon />}
            label="Toggle Admin"
            onClick={toggleAdmin(params.id)}
            showInMenu
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<FileCopyIcon />}
            label="Duplicate User"
            onClick={duplicateUser(params.id)}
            showInMenu
          />,
        ],
      },
], [deleteUser, toggleAdmin, duplicateUser]);
```